# Why is my server (runs in thread) not recieving the DatagramPackage?

Tags: java, multithreading, server

Edit: I made a boiled down version of my code which seems to have the same problem:

```
import java.net.*;

public class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //message1
        String s = "bla";
        try{
            testServer t = new testServer();
            Thread serve = new Thread(t);
            serve.start();

            DatagramSocket sock = new DatagramSocket();
            sock.connect(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),54636);
            DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(s.getBytes(),s.getBytes().length);
            //Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("sending message");
            sock.send(dp);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}

class testServer implements  Runnable{
    public void run(){
        try{
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
            socket.connect(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),54636);
            byte[] buf = new byte[500];
            DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            System.out.println("Server waits for message.");
            socket.receive(dp);
            String a = new String(dp.getData());
            System.out.println(a);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a server thread that connects to a Datagram Socket (localhost, 54636(<-random)). Then I try to send a message to the server, but it does not receive it.

P.S.: sry that I am so unspecific, but I have no idea what's causing the problem :( and thank you for your help :)

Comment: Are you running the two server/client on the same system? With UDP packets its easy for it to get dropped or blocked. I am not familiar with the code itself and what is is doing short of reviewing your git repo.

Comment: Yes. I define the port and adress in main and save it in RemoteRef which is just an address and a port. then I create the server thread and the socket is initialised with the address and port from the remoteRef and the run method basically calls the socket.recieve(dp) and stays there. main then calls a function which uses a different socket with the same address and port to send a package (socket.send(dp)) and then calls socket.recieve(dp) to get the answer from the server. That ends with both threads being stack at socket,reieve()  (both sockets have different names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `testServer` replace the following lines:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
socket.connect(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),54636);
```

with:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),54636);
```

---

Edit:

I strongly suggest you take a look at [Writing a Datagram Client and Server](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html) Java trail for more info on how datagram socket programming works.

You simply were not using the API correctly.

Comment: That worked! So for sending messages back and forth I have to disconnect to receive the message and reconnect again to send?